# how to generate a key pair and used that for the encryption / decryption in C using openssl library?

Tags: c, openssl

what i am trying to find a way to automatically generate key pair to be used for encryption and decryption from program itself?

currently, i am using sample key in my program and able to perform encryption/decryption on string data using Openssl library.

Comment: https://msol.io/blog/tech/create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-with-openssl/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EVP_PKEY_keygen()` and associated functions. The man page (which includes an example) is here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_PKEY_keygen.html